# Data loss under Linux

Tags: linux, data-recovery, fsck

I work under linux debian buster.

This morning I worked as usual and my PC crashed. I forced it to shut down and when I restarted, it presents the terminal with initramfs (if I'm not mistaken) by inviting me to do an fsck.

This is not the first time this has happened to me. I usually do an

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

then

```
fsck -y /dev/sda3
```

for my root and home partition.
But this morning, after crashing, when I did that, he scrolled through several messages quickly, and that worried me. At the end I restarted my PC and voila, I can no longer find my work folder.

In fact, I have a folder containing two other folders. Hey there is only one visible folder left. All of my shortcuts to the missing folder no longer works.

When I make a `df -h`, the size appears as if the file is present, but impossible to see it. It is not in `/lost+found`

I have a global search in my home, and nothing

I can no longer work, all my work was there, I have a 1 month old backup, but good.

If really really, you have a solution, please I'm desperate.

My disk is partitioned into 4 including 3 for linux and one for ntfs

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome on Unix.SE. Could you elaborate on "crashed"? How did you know it crashed? I mean, did it end up rebooting on you (doesn't sound like it). But what exactly makes you think it crashed? Was it unresponsive to user input? In a situation such as the one your question seems to suggest, you better use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) to perform an emergency sync. But it stands to readon that you misinterpreted the unresponsiveness of the machine while it was sluggish due to I/O and so on (this would fit the symptom upon reboot).

Comment: Did the `fsck` actually perform any repairs? Btw, personally I'd first use a "dry run" without the `-y`. When you attempted to list the contents of your disk(s) you considered that files and folders with a leading dot are by convention hidden and so `tree -a` or `ls -a` would have to be used to make them visible? Also, could it be your home folder was encrypted and required some sort of mounting to become accessible (which may be transparent during normal logon, but matters in recovery scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

too happy
I found my data.
What made me have 0.5% of hope (I must admit I was at the edge of the window with the pc and looking for my data one last time), was the size of my partition. When I right click on home and I look at the size I have 31go, and with a
df -h
and as a result:
/ dev / sda3 192G 95G 87G 53% / home

or 95 GB of used, compared to 31 GB above, so where are the 60 GB?
Before the problem, I was around 95 GB in size.

It is true that several messages including the word inode or node (I do not remember) with numbers quickly appeared during fsck -y

Someone suggested I take a look at / home / lost + found, and when I did, I saw nothing. But when I logged in as root in a terminal, then "cd / home" and ls lost + found ", I saw numbers like # 13032 # 13036 # 1181667, and a folder with the number # 4703. So I made a "chmod 777 -R lost + found" in order to be able to access it via my account (simple user account). Once the command was executed and after a few minutes, I opened / home / lost + found via a "nemo" file explorer and TADAM, all my data was there.
I’ve done SEVERAL SAVINGS and vowed not to trust fsck -y anymore, even though it’s a great tool, but I’ll use it with caution.